# Domain name nameserver error

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

Recently, I've been experiencing some downtime for my website www.nexttwist.com.

The downtime is intermittent and it may be up at one location while it is down in another physical location. For some users, when they change the DNS to 8.8.8.8 in their system, they've reported that it came back.

I then had a look into my DNS settings at http://www.intodns.com/nexttwist.com and found the errors (attached image):

[image]

I don't know if the error as shown is responsible for the downtime but can anyone explain me how to fix these errors?

Comment: How you fix it depends on how it's supposed to work. Who is supposed to be providing name service for your domain and what nameservers did they tell you to use?

Comment: I'm hosting my application at AWS. There are no NS records in my DNS settings, I've an A record pointing to the host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there's an inconsistency between what your registrar has in their database and what they pushed into the `.com` TLD database. If you didn't change it recently (in the past two hours or so), I'd talk to your registrar.

Domainmonster.com says:

```
Nameserver:             ns1.domainmonster.com
Nameserver:             ns2.domainmonster.com
Nameserver:             ns3.domainmonster.com
```

But the `.com` servers say:

```
nexttwist.com   nameserver = ns1.domainmonster.com.
nexttwist.com   nameserver = ns2.domainmonster.com.
nexttwist.com   nameserver = ns3.domainmonster.com.
nexttwist.com   nameserver = dns3.registrar-servers.com.
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check with the registrar then. Just for my clarity, these two must be the same, right? (Pardon my ignorance)

Comment: They don't absolutely have to be the same. But the problem in this case is that `dns3.registrar-servers.com` is not actually providing any name service for your domain, and the `.com` master servers are directing people to it. This can cause their nameservers to time out.